# Why in scala a comparison between integer and floating point such as 71 == 71.0 is true?

Tags: scala, equality

I got this in the scala interpreter:

```
scala> val a:Float = 71F; val b:Int = 71; if (a==b) println ("?")
?
a: Float = 71.0
b: Int = 71
```

And I was wondering what are the exact semantics of this comparison. Even though I have a superficial knowledge of Scala I guess floating number arithmetic (and in this case I'm making sure of not using something equivalent to java's BigDecimal, or at least so I think) applies to this example. So "a" is not holding the number 71, as "b" is, but something close to it.

I think making any integer to floating point comparison yield false would have simplified things, but I am sure I must be missing something.

On a side note, I wonder if this could lead to any bugs in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same thing happens in Java, as specified in [JLS 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1). Scala probably inherits this semantics for compatibility.

Comment: I knew about Java, but I couldn't find how it works for Scala. (I also would expect Scala to work in a different way and make a more clever use of its complex type system)

Comment: @Jubbat Sure it may be a burden, but changing such fundamental things like numerical operator semantics would probably be very harmful as the Java semantics is now ubiquitous.

Answer (score 2):

This comportment is inherited from Java due to an implicit conversion, as you can see in the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int)

```
Implicit information
    This member is added by an implicit conversion from Int to Integer performed by method int2Integer in scala.Predef.
```

For a safer equals, use `===` from Scalaz